# clearInterval "var is undefined" |

Tags: javascript, clearinterval

I want my timer to stop and reload to 0 when it hits 25 with a `clearInterval` but it says that the variable `refreshInterval` is `undefined`. The timer resets but it keeps on going and I want it completely to stop until its enabled again.

```js
function removeMe() {
  var refreshInterval = setInterval(setTime, 1000);
  display.removeBen();
  totalSeconds = 0;
};

//timer1//
var minutesLabel = document.getElementById("minutes");
var secondsLabel = document.getElementById("seconds");
var totalSeconds = 0;

function setTime() {
  if (totalSeconds == 1) {
    game.clickValue + 2;
  }
  if (totalSeconds == 25) {
    game.clickValue - 2;
    clearInterval(refreshInterval);
    totalSeconds = 0;
  } else
    ++totalSeconds;
  secondsLabel.innerHTML = pad(totalSeconds % 60);
  minutesLabel.innerHTML = pad(parseInt(totalSeconds / 60));
}

function pad(val) {
  var valString = val + "";
  if (valString.length < 2) {
    return "0" + valString;
  } else {
    return valString;
  }
}
//timer1//
```

Comment: That's true. `refreshInterval` is only declared inside `removeMe`. If you want it to be accessible to `setTime` you have to declare it in an environment that's accessible to both `removeMe` and `setTime`.

Comment: How can I do this?

Comment: Put `var refreshInterval;` above `function removeMe() {` and change `var refreshInterval = setInterval(...)` to `refreshInterval = setInterval(...)`.

Comment: I'd suggest you read up on [variable scopes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var)

Comment: [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/500431)

Answer (score 0):

Move `refreshInterval` up to the global scope so that is accessible from within both the `removeMe` and `setTime` function scopes.

```js
let refreshInterval;

function removeMe() {
  refreshInterval = setInterval(setTime, 1000);
};

//timer1//
var minutesLabel = document.getElementById("minutes");
var secondsLabel = document.getElementById("seconds");
var totalSeconds = 0;

function setTime() {
  if (totalSeconds == 25) {
    clearInterval(refreshInterval);
    totalSeconds = 0;
  } else
    ++totalSeconds;
  secondsLabel.innerHTML = pad(totalSeconds % 60);
  minutesLabel.innerHTML = pad(parseInt(totalSeconds / 60));
}

function pad(val) {
  var valString = val + "";
  if (valString.length < 2) {
    return "0" + valString;
  } else {
    return valString;
  }
}


removeMe()
```

```html
<p id="minutes"></p>
<p id="seconds"></p>
```